# Let $f : [a; b] \to \mathbb R$ defined by...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $f : [a; b]  \to \mathbb R$ defined by
> $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> c,  & x=a \\
> d, & a \lt x \lt b\\ 
> e, & x=b
> \end{cases}$$
> Assuming $c \lt d \lt e$, show that $f$ is integrable into $[a, b]$ and that
> $$ \int_a^b f = d(b-a).$$

[image]

**My attempt:**

Let $P: a=t_0 + t_1 + ... + t_{n-1} + t_n = b$ then

$ \sum_{j=1}^n w_j(t_j - t_{j-1}) = w_1(t_1 - a) + w_2(t_2 - t_1) + w_3(t_3 - t_2) + ... + w_j(b- t_{j-1}) $ but

$w_2 = w_3 = ... = w_{j-1} = 0$ and

$ w_1 = (d-c), w_j = (e-d)$ so

$ \sum_{j=1}^n w_j(t_j - t_{j-1}) = (d-c)(t_1 - a) + (e-d)(b- t_{j-1}) $

now, given a $\epsilon \gt0$ there is a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that

$(d-c)(t_1 - a) + (e-d)(b- t_{j-1}) = \sum_{j=1}^n w_j(t_j - t_{j-1}) \lt \epsilon$

given a $ \ epsilon$ choose $t_1 \lt a$ such that $(d-c)(t_1 - a) \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$  and

$t_{n-1} \lt b$ such that $(d-c)(t_1 - a) \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Thus, if $P = \{a, t_1, t_{n-1}, b \}$ then $P$ is a partition of $[a,b]$

$\sum_{j=1}^n w_j(t_j - t_{j-1}) = (d-c)(t_1 - a) + (e-d)(b- t_{j-1}) \lt \frac{\epsilon} {2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$

As it is integrable, then the upper integral and the lower integral are equal, so using the lower integral we have:

$$ \int_{a}^b f = \sup s(f;p) = \sum_{j=1}^n m_j(t_j - t_{j-1}) = \sum_{j=1}^n d(b-a) = d \sum_{j=1}^n (b-a) = d(b-a)$$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function you have given is not well defined at "a"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For integrability, given $ \epsilon>0 $, consider the partition $ P : $
$$(a=t_0, a+\frac{\epsilon}{2(d-c)}=t_1,b-\frac{\epsilon}{2(e-d)}=t_2,b=t_3)$$

then, if $ L(f,P) $ and $ U(f,P) $ are the lower and upper Darboux sums, we have

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

For the value of the integrale,

the function$$ F :x\mapsto \int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^xf(t)dt $$
is continuous, thus

$$\int_a^bf(t)dt=\lim_{x\to 0}\int_{a+x}^{b-x}f(t)dt$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}d(b-2x-a)=d(b-a)$$